# Always open a new terminal when clicking the terminal icon

Tags: workspaces

Operating system: Ubuntu 19.10

Problem: Clicking terminal in workspace two displays workspace one again

I have the original logged-in workspace up. I click on terminal to display it and type in workspace one so I will know where I am. I display another workspace and single-click on terminal. I expected a new terminal to appear but I am just back to the original workspace.

I select a new workspace again and perform right-click on terminal and select new window. Now I have two separate work spaces. I assume that is the only way this thing works. Am I correct on that?

Answer (score 3):

It can be assumed you are using the standard version of Ubuntu 19.10.

**Short answer**: When you are in the second workspace <kbd>Shift</kbd>click on the terminal to open a new terminal in the second workspace.

**Background**: By default, Ubuntu 19.10 icons behave as "Launch or switch to". Clicking an icon will launch an application (for example the terminal) if it is not yet running. If it is running, Ubuntu instead will switch you to an already existing instance, which in your case is the terminal on workspace 1. Some people may like that because it reduces clutter of having each time additional windows if a terminal is already open.

You can overrule that behaviour by holding Shift before clicking the icon. Then, a new instance will always be launched.

**Changing the system behaviour**

If you rather wish that clicking an icon *always* opens a new instance of an application, then you can change the default behavior of the system as following.

1 Install `gnome-shell-extensions` by opening a terminal and entering following command:

```
sudo apt get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

This installs a number of official Gnome Shell extensions.

2 Activate one of the extensions. For this, you need to install an additional tool, "Gnome Tweaks". You can find that in the software center. Once installed, launch that configuration utility by searching for "Tweaks". On the Extensions tab, find the "Launch new instance" extension and activate it.